# copy a graph (adjacency_list) to another one

Tags: c++, boost, copy, boost-graph

How can I copy a graph of type adjacency_list to another one graph of type adjacency_list ?

```
typedef adjacency_list<setS, setS, undirectedS, NodeDataStruct, EdgeDataStruct> MyGraph;
MyGraph g1, g2;

// processing g1: adding vertices and edges ...
// processing g2: adding some vertices and edges ...

g1.clear();
g1 = g2 // this gives an execution error (exception)
g1 = MyGraph(g2); // this also gives an execution error
g2.clear();
```

Comment: I know this is old. I wonder if you needed to define the copy constructor for your vertex and edge properties. I recently needed to copy a graph and the copy constructor worked fine for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried [copy_graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/copy_graph.html)?

---

Hard to know what the problem is without seeing the errors but if I had to guess, I'd first make sure you're providing a `vertex_index` map to `copy_graph` since it's not available by default when you use `setS` for vertex storage.  Based on your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935417/how-provide-a-vertex-index-property-for-my-graph), it looks like you've already got that figured out so we just need to bring it all together.

```
  typedef adjacency_list<setS, setS, undirectedS, NodeDataStruct, EdgeDataStruct> MyGraph;
  typedef MyGraph::vertex_descriptor NodeID;

  typedef map<NodeID, size_t> IndexMap;
  IndexMap mapIndex;
  associative_property_map<IndexMap> propmapIndex(mapIndex);

  MyGraph g1, g2;

  // processing g1: adding vertices and edges ...
  // processing g2: adding some vertices and edges ...

  int i=0;
  BGL_FORALL_VERTICES(v, g2, MyGraph)
  {
     put(propmapIndex, v, i++);
  }

  g1.clear();
  copy_graph( g2, g1, vertex_index_map( propmapIndex ) );
  g2.clear();
```

Comment: For copy_graph it is said that the graph type must be a model of VertexListGraph. In my case I've said that it is an adjacency_list.

Comment: @user995434 But adjacency_list is a model of VertexAndEdgeListGraph which is a refinement of VertexListGraph.  Hence adjacency_list is a model of VertexListGraph.

Comment: Can you please give a small illustrative example of using copy_graph() for what I would like to do ? It always give me compilation errors. Thanks in advance.