# On C++ Boost Graph Creation and the vertex_index Property.

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

I am boost noob. I am wondering why compilation fails in the following code. I am creating a set of vertices, and trying to assign my own vertex indices and vertex names. (I am following this page: http://fireflyblue.blogspot.com/2008/01/boost-graph-library.html. )

I understand that `vertS` vertex lists in `Boost` does not need explicit vertex id creations, and I have also seen this very related question in Stackoverflow ([how provide a vertex_index property for my graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935417/how-provide-a-vertex-index-property-for-my-graph)) which discusses how to use an `associative_property_map` to assign vertex indices. The following though - getting the vertex_index map, and assigning the key value pairs -  seems a fairly straightforward thing to do, and I would like to understand why it fails. Any help is greatly appreciated!

The compile error is as below:

`error: expression is not assignable
    vertIndx[v] = i;`

```
//Define graph
typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string> sv_namePty;
typedef boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int, sv_namePty > sv_indx_n_name_pty;
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int> se_weightPty;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, 
        sv_indx_n_name_pty, se_weightPty> ScafGraph;

//descriptors
typedef boost::graph_traits<ScafGraph>::vertex_descriptor SV;
typedef boost::graph_traits<ScafGraph>::edge_descriptor SE;

//Graph Object
ScafGraph SG;

//property accessors
boost::property_map<ScafGraph, 
     boost::vertex_name_t>::type vertName = boost::get(boost::vertex_name, SG);
boost::property_map<ScafGraph, 
     boost::vertex_index_t>::type vertIndx = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, SG);
boost::property_map<ScafGraph, 
     boost::edge_weight_t>::type edgeWeight = boost::get(boost::edge_weight, SG);

//Populate Graph
std::vector<SV> svlist;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    SV v = boost::add_vertex(SG);
    svlist.push_back(v);
    vertName[v] = std::to_string(i);
    vertIndx[v] = i;
}
```

Comment: Property maps are mysterious and difficult to use.  Strongly reccomend you use bundled properties instead - they are much easier and intuitive.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html

Comment: I have just started looking in to it following your comment; thanks! It indeed seems a lot more manageable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `vertIndx[v]` returns a Vertex by value. Thus you get the error because it's not an lvalue when you try to assign to it.

Furthermore, it actually returns `v`. Here's the code run by `vertIndx[v]`:

```
inline value_type operator[](key_type v) const { return v; }
```

Here's a version that is hopefully clear about how it works:

```
#include <boost\graph\adjacency_list.hpp>

int main()
{
    //Define graph
    typedef boost::adjacency_list
        <
            boost::vecS                                        //! edge list 
          , boost::vecS                                        //! vertex list
          , boost::undirectedS                                 //! undirected graph  
          , boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string> //! vertex properties : name                
          , boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int>         //! edge properties : weight 
        >   ScafGraph;

    //descriptors
    typedef boost::graph_traits<ScafGraph>::vertex_descriptor SV;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<ScafGraph>::edge_descriptor SE;

    //Graph Object
    ScafGraph SG;

    //property accessors
    boost::property_map<ScafGraph,
        boost::vertex_name_t>::type vertName = boost::get(boost::vertex_name, SG);
    boost::property_map<ScafGraph,
        boost::vertex_index_t>::type vertIndx = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, SG);
    boost::property_map<ScafGraph,
        boost::edge_weight_t>::type edgeWeight = boost::get(boost::edge_weight, SG);

    //Populate Graph
    std::vector<SV> svlist;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        SV v = boost::add_vertex(ScafGraph::vertex_property_type(std::to_string(i)), SG);
        svlist.push_back(v);
        assert(vertName[v] == std::to_string(i));
        assert(vertIndx[v] == i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 1) Does this mean the behavior of vertName in my code was also not what I wanted it to be (assigning names to vertex descriptors)? 2) The `ScafGraph::vertex_property_type(std::to_string(i))` I suspect is providing the vertex its name; is it possible to show how one would assign their own indices instead of the default ones using a construct like this? Thanks!

Comment: I believe setting the name property when the vertex is added might be slightly more efficient.

As for custom indices, I think that for the adjacency_list it's always the case that the vertex_descriptor maps to the index value. This is because they are one and the same. If you use a graph type that isn't random access it uses void* as the descriptor. In that case the map is non-trivial (maps void* to the index). I suspect you can't change the index in that case either. You can always add your own custom properties and assign them whatever you like.

Comment: Some explanation on how to assign all the 3 properties `vertex_name_t`, `vertex_index_t` and `edge_weight_t` would do a lot of good to this answer.