# C++ graph with removable nodes, accessible properties and reliable IDs

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph, lemon-graph-library

I'm trying to **migrate** from a proprietary graph library **to** an Open Source one.

EDIT: since so few people seem to know how Boost Graph actually works, if you can provide a solution using the LEMON Graph Library, that's fine too.

Currently, my vertices have type `Graph_Vertex*` and can have an associated `void*` pointer to store related information. A similar logic is used with respect to edges, which are of type `Graph_Edge*`. I use the `void*` pointer to store my own structure `Node_State`, which is something like this

```
struct Node_State {
    std::string name;
    int id;
    // other stuff
};
```

From what I've seen of the BGL up to now, I could create a graph using an `adjacency_list` structure and [bundled properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html) to point to my `Node_State`. Then, instead of using **vertex pointers**, I would use integer **vertex indices**.

I've been looking at the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/quick_tour.html) and some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25061033) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8812466), and this seems possible. I'm thinking about something like

```
typedef adjacency_list < listS, vecS, bidirectionalS, Node_State> gr;
```

I'll remove all the edges to and from a vertex from time to time. Very less frequently, I may remove a node too. That's why I would choose `listS, vecS`.

I would like to make it easy to create a second version of this structure for undirected edges. I am not sure if `bidirectionalS` is the best option for my case. Your input is appreciated in this regard.

There's another problem though. Right now, I can use an external **map** to find each vertex by its **name** or using a unique integer **id**.

```
std::map<int, Graph_Vertex*> nodes_by_id;
std::map<std::string, Graph_Vertex*> nodes_by_name();
```

If I delete a vertex, I just need to remove the corresponding entry(ies) in the map(s), and things keep working.

From what I understand, this is not so easy to achieve with BGL, because deleting a vertex triggers the **renumbering** of all the vertices with a higher ID, and might also cause a reallocation of the internal structures. So goodbye ids and goodbye pointers.

*Main question.* Is it possible to create a `map<name, node>` or `map<index, node>` that can survive node **removals** with minimal adjustments (e.g. just removing the invalid keys)? If not, what's the best way to map nodes to some unique identifier that survives modifications to the graph?

An option could be using the [internal properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec:adjacency-list-properties). Tutorial [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec:custom-vertex-properties) here.

```
struct vertex_index_t { };
struct edge_index_t { };

struct vertex_name_t { };
struct edge_name_t { };
```

And keeping some external structures

```
std::map<vertex_index_t, Graph_Vertex*> nodes_by_id;
std::map<vertex_name_t, Graph_Vertex*> nodes_by_name;
std::map<edge_index_t, Graph_Edge*> edges_by_id;
std::map<edge_name_t, Graph_Edge*> edges_by_name;
```

This would be much more similar to what I have now, and require less changes to the current code.

I haven't really understood how `vertex_index_t` is affected by vertex removal, and how `vertex_name_t` can be assigned. If this can work, though, a similar logic could be applied to edges using `edge_index_t` and `edge_name_t` too.

Wrap up. I need a working piece of code showing how to:

- add vertices (with properties)
- add arcs (with properties)
- remove vertices
- remove arcs

With these important requisites:

- being able to index vertices by id (int or string) so that it's easy to retrieve them and access their properties
- ids must not change if a vertex is removed
- the addition of indices and properties should not make running algorithms like "find connected components" and "Dijkstra search" more difficult

I would be happy if I could achieve something like

```
Vertex* vertex0 = Graph.get_vertex_by_name("v0");
Vertex_Data* v0_data = vertex0.get_data();

Edge* edge4 = Graph.get_edge_by_id(4);
Edge_Data* e4_data = edge4.get_data();
```

This may seem like a lot of questions, but really just the basis of what I need to get this library up and running. Anything less and it's completely useless for what I need to do.

Please, hit all the bullet points.

Think of this as a tutorial, my hope is that giving a bounty will help other people as well.

Answer (score 6):

> Then, instead of using vertex pointers, I would use integer vertex indices.

In fact, I think you would use vertex descriptors. Which in the case of vecS container selections would be integral, yes

> From what I understand, this is not so easy to achieve with BGL, because deleting a vertex triggers the renumbering of all the vertices with a higher ID, and might also cause a reallocation of the internal structures.

Strictly speaking this is not always the case. It **is** the case with `vecS`, but not with e.g. `listS` (lists have stable iterators).

- [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

All in all, I suggest looking at `listS` as the container selection and drop the assumption that `vertex_descriptor` be an integral type (it will become opaque).

In return for iterator stability, you will need to provide vertex index maps to certain algorithms.

Comment: When using `listS` it is somewhat trickier to provide a vertex_index_t map. You have to decide where you store the mapping: vertex --> integer where integer should be in the interval [0,num_vertices(g)).
Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336723/bgl-dijkstra-shortest-path-algorithm-method-does-not-accept-my-color-map-exterio/19717509#19717509 it was done using the vertex property. You can also use some separate std::map. In any case, the key element is to add that template specialization `namespace boost { template<> struct property_map<MyGraph, vertex_index_t > {... };  } `

Comment: @MichaelSimbirsky most algorithms take an optional vertex_index (named) parameter, what's the added value of using the specialization?

Comment: No problem at all. I remember our ~1 hour conversation in chat [about  Learning Boost Graph (among other things)](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/learning-boost-graph). _Re: "What examples?"_: Specifically [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29109054/29110540#comment46456000_29110540). For the rest, search: [how provide a vertex_index property for my graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935417/how-provide-a-vertex-index-property-for-my-graph) could help, this one [shows how pass an index_map when using `vecS`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28376521/85371);

Comment: Thanks, fascinated by your contributions in StackOverflow and in boost-graph in particular. Always enjoy you comments. 

I often write adapters converting existing structures to Boost.Graph interface. For example, for primal and dual graphs of Boost.Polygon Voronoi diagram. In all such cases I consider vertex_index to be a natural part of the adapter. The moment one defines a graph, there usually exists a natural vertex numbering.

I prefer to make this numbering explicit to spare the user of my code from the trouble of defining his or her own vertex index map.