# Boost graph library: Get the order number of a specific vertex?

Tags: boost

Boost graphic library has a function `vertex_descriptor vertex(vertices_size_type n, const adjacency_list& g)`, which returns the nth `vertex_descriptor`. What is the inverse of this function? That is, to obtain the order number of a given `vertex_descriptor`?

Comment: **[Vertex Order](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VertexOrder.html)** means something else in graph theory: _"The number of graph edges meeting at a given node in a graph is called the order of that graph vertex."_

Comment: You'd better call this _index_ or somesuch. "Order" is already used to mean something else, and "order number" has never been a clear way to discuss something's index within a collection.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Thanks. I called it this name because there is a `vertex_index_t` internal property in this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an *efficient* way, generically, because it depends on how the vertices are stored.

If you don't care for performance you could create a function like this:

```
template <typename Graph>
size_t index_of(Graph const& g, typename Graph::vertex_descriptor const& vd)
{
    auto vs = vertices(g);
    auto lookup = std::find(vs.first, vs.second, vd);
    assert(lookup != vs.second);

    return std::distance(vs.first, lookup);
}
```

In the "comprehensive" test below it is shown to work for a plethora of different configurations of `adjacency_list<>` graph types.

The performance of the above should be reasonable with `vecS` storage, but it could be abysmal if otherwise. In such cases, it would be far better to supply your own `vertex_index` mapping, as many other algorithms do require (e.g. `write_graphviz`):

- **[how provide a vertex_index property for my graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935417/how-provide-a-vertex-index-property-for-my-graph)**

---

#### Test Program

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d047ea7f55e30525)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

using namespace boost;

template <typename Graph>
size_t index_of(Graph const& g, typename Graph::vertex_descriptor const& vd)
{
    auto vs = vertices(g);
    auto lookup = std::find(vs.first, vs.second, vd);
    assert(lookup != vs.second);

    return std::distance(vs.first, lookup);
}

static mt19937 rnd(time(0));

template <typename Graph, size_t num_vertices = 200, size_t num_edges = 300>
void test_index_of()
{
    Graph g;
    generate_random_graph(g, 100, 300, rnd);

    for(auto const& v : make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        assert(v == boost::vertex(index_of(g, v), g));
    }
}

int main()
{
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<vecS,  vecS,  undirectedS> >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<vecS,  setS,  undirectedS> >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<vecS,  listS, undirectedS> >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<setS,  vecS,  undirectedS> >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<setS,  setS,  undirectedS> >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<setS,  listS, undirectedS> >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<listS, vecS,  undirectedS> >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<listS, setS,  undirectedS> >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<listS, listS, undirectedS> >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<vecS,  vecS,  directedS>   >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<vecS,  setS,  directedS>   >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<vecS,  listS, directedS>   >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<setS,  vecS,  directedS>   >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<setS,  setS,  directedS>   >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<setS,  listS, directedS>   >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<listS, vecS,  directedS>   >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<listS, setS,  directedS>   >();
    test_index_of<adjacency_list<listS, listS, directedS>   >();
}
```