# Forming reference to void when getting property map from a bundled property

Tags: c++, boost-graph

My `Graph` type is defined as follows:

```
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<vecS, setS, directedS, State, CostType>;
```

where `CostType` happens to be `int`.

I am trying to obtain the Kamada-Kawai spring layout as follows:

```
template <class PointMap>
PointMap layout() const {
    PointMap res;
    boost::associative_property_map<PointMap> temp(res);
    circle_graph_layout(g_, temp, 10.0);

    // http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html
    bool ok = kamada_kawai_spring_layout(
        g_, temp, get(edge_bundle, g_),
        square_topology<>(50.0), side_length(50.0));
    (void)ok;
    //boost::BOOST_CHECK(ok);
    return res;
}
```

The compiler (`gcc` version 4.8.2) complains about creating a reference to `void`. I have checked that the circular layout works. What am I doing wrong in the call to `kamada_kawai_spring_layout`?

Here is a partial output by `gcc`:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/SearchLib/AstarWithPolicies/" -*-
Compilation started at Tue Nov 24 22:54:48

make -k 
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++11 -pedantic -I ~/boost_1_59_0 -I /usr/include/cairomm-1.0/ -I /usr/include/cairo/ -I /usr/include/sigc++-2.0/ -I /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include/ -I /usr/include/freetype2/ -o Test Test.cpp -g -lcairo -lX11
In file included from /home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:246:0,
                 from Graph.h:10,
                 from Astar.h:5,
                 from Test.cpp:4:
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::adj_list_any_vertex_pa::bind_<boost::vertex_index_t, boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, Pancake>’:
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2613:12:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::adj_list_choose_vertex_pa<boost::vertex_index_t, boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, Pancake>’
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2750:12:   required from ‘struct boost::adj_list_vertex_property_selector::bind_<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, Pancake, boost::vertex_index_t>’
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/properties.hpp:201:12:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::vertex_index_t>’
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/properties.hpp:212:10:   required from ‘struct boost::property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::vertex_index_t, void>’
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:1733:5:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Config, class Base, class Property> typename boost::property_map<typename Config::graph_type, Property>::const_type boost::get(Property, const boost::adj_list_helper<Config, Base>&) [with Config = boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config; Base = boost::directed_graph_helper<boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config>; Property = boost::vertex_index_t]’
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.hpp:618:58:   required from ‘bool boost::kamada_kawai_spring_layout(const Graph&, PositionMap, WeightMap, const Topology&, boost::detail::graph::edge_or_side<EdgeOrSideLength, T>) [with Topology = boost::square_topology<>; Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::directedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>; PositionMap = boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point> > > >; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::directed_tag, int, const int&, void*, const int, boost::edge_bundle_t>; T = double; bool EdgeOrSideLength = false]’
Graph.h:106:55:   required from ‘PointMap StateGraph<StateNeighbor>::layout() const [with PointMap = std::map<void*, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point> > >; StateNeighbor = StateNeighbor<Pancake>]’
Drawer.h:60:75:   required from ‘Drawer<Graph>::Drawer(const Graph&) [with Graph = StateGraph<StateNeighbor<Pancake> >]’
Test.cpp:34:22:   required from here
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2543:29: error: forming reference to void
         typedef value_type& reference;
```

**UPDATE 1**: the same error occurs if I change the graph type to `undirectedS`.

**UPDATE 2**: Thanks to the comments, this is the improved version that uses an index map:

```
template <class PointMap>
PointMap layout() const {
    PointMap res;
    boost::associative_property_map<PointMap> temp(res);
    circle_graph_layout(g_, temp, 10.0);

    // https://stackoverflow.com/q/33903879/2725810
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/8555715/2725810
    typedef std::map<VertexDescriptor, std::size_t> IndexMap;
    IndexMap mapIndex;
    associative_property_map<IndexMap> propmapIndex(mapIndex);
    // http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html
    kamada_kawai_spring_layout(g_, temp, get(edge_bundle, g_),
                               square_topology<>(50.0), side_length(50.0),
                               layout_tolerance<CostType>(),
                               CostType(1), propmapIndex);
    return res;
}
```

This still does not satisfy `gcc` though:

```
In file included from Graph.h:13:0,
                 from Astar.h:5,
                 from Test.cpp:4:
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.hpp: In instantiation of ‘bool boost::detail::graph::kamada_kawai_spring_layout_impl<Topology, Graph, PositionMap, WeightMap, EdgeOrSideLength, Done, VertexIndexMap, DistanceMatrix, SpringStrengthMatrix, PartialDerivativeMap>::run() [with Topology = boost::square_topology<>; Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::undirectedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>; PositionMap = boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point> > > >; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, int, const int&, void*, const int, boost::edge_bundle_t>; EdgeOrSideLength = boost::detail::graph::edge_or_side<false, double>; Done = boost::layout_tolerance<int>; VertexIndexMap = boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, long unsigned int, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, long unsigned int> > > >; DistanceMatrix = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > > >; SpringStrengthMatrix = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > > >; PartialDerivativeMap = boost::iterator_property_map<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference*, std::vector<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference, std::allocator<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference> > >, boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, long unsigned int, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, long unsigned int> > > >, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference&>]’:
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.hpp:524:20:   required from ‘bool boost::kamada_kawai_spring_layout(const Graph&, PositionMap, WeightMap, const Topology&, boost::detail::graph::edge_or_side<EdgeOrSideLength, T>, Done, typename boost::property_traits<DistanceMap>::value_type, VertexIndexMap, DistanceMatrix, SpringStrengthMatrix, PartialDerivativeMap) [with Topology = boost::square_topology<>; Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::undirectedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>; PositionMap = boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point> > > >; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, int, const int&, void*, const int, boost::edge_bundle_t>; T = double; bool EdgeOrSideLength = false; Done = boost::layout_tolerance<int>; VertexIndexMap = boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, long unsigned int, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, long unsigned int> > > >; DistanceMatrix = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > > >; SpringStrengthMatrix = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > > >; PartialDerivativeMap = boost::iterator_property_map<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference*, std::vector<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference, std::allocator<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference> > >, boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, long unsigned int, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, long unsigned int> > > >, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference&>; typename boost::property_traits<DistanceMap>::value_type = int]’
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.hpp:559:79:   required from ‘bool boost::kamada_kawai_spring_layout(const Graph&, PositionMap, WeightMap, const Topology&, boost::detail::graph::edge_or_side<EdgeOrSideLength, T>, Done, typename boost::property_traits<DistanceMap>::value_type, VertexIndexMap) [with Topology = boost::square_topology<>; Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::undirectedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>; PositionMap = boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point> > > >; WeightMap = boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, int, const int&, void*, const int, boost::edge_bundle_t>; T = double; bool EdgeOrSideLength = false; Done = boost::layout_tolerance<int>; VertexIndexMap = boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, long unsigned int, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, long unsigned int> > > >; typename boost::property_traits<DistanceMap>::value_type = int]’
Graph.h:112:61:   required from ‘PointMap StateGraph<StateNeighbor>::layout() const [with PointMap = std::map<void*, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point> > >; StateNeighbor = StateNeighbor<Pancake>]’
Drawer.h:60:75:   required from ‘Drawer<Graph>::Drawer(const Graph&) [with Graph = StateGraph<StateNeighbor<Pancake> >]’
Test.cpp:34:22:   required from here
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.hpp:313:96: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::detail::graph::linear_solver<2ul>::solve(boost::detail::graph::kamada_kawai_spring_layout_impl<boost::square_topology<>, boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::undirectedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point> > > >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, int, const int&, void*, const int, boost::edge_bundle_t>, boost::detail::graph::edge_or_side<false, double>, boost::layout_tolerance<int>, boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, long unsigned int, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, long unsigned int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > > >, boost::iterator_property_map<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference*, std::vector<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference, std::allocator<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference> > >, boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, long unsigned int, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, long unsigned int> > > >, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference&> >::weight_type [2][2], boost::detail::graph::kamada_kawai_spring_layout_impl<boost::square_topology<>, boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::undirectedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point> > > >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, int, const int&, void*, const int, boost::edge_bundle_t>, boost::detail::graph::edge_or_side<false, double>, boost::layout_tolerance<int>, boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, long unsigned int, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, long unsigned int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > > >, boost::iterator_property_map<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference*, std::vector<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference, std::allocator<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference> > >, boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, long unsigned int, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, long unsigned int> > > >, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference&> >::deriv_type&)’
 _difference_type delta = -linear_solver<Point::dimensions>::solve(dE_d_d, dE_d);
                                                                               ^
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.hpp:313:96: note: candidate is:
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.hpp:95:18: note: template<class Vec> static Vec boost::detail::graph::linear_solver<2ul>::solve(double (*)[2], Vec)
       static Vec solve(double mat[2][2], Vec rhs) {
                  ^
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.hpp:95:18: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/meir/boost_1_59_0/boost/graph/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.hpp:313:96: note:   cannot convert ‘dE_d_d’ (type ‘boost::detail::graph::kamada_kawai_spring_layout_impl<boost::square_topology<>, boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::setS, boost::undirectedS, Pancake, int, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point> > > >, boost::adj_list_edge_property_map<boost::undirected_tag, int, const int&, void*, const int, boost::edge_bundle_t>, boost::detail::graph::edge_or_side<false, double>, boost::layout_tolerance<int>, boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, long unsigned int, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, long unsigned int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > > >, boost::iterator_property_map<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference*, std::vector<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference, std::allocator<boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference> > >, boost::associative_property_map<std::map<void*, long unsigned int, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<std::pair<void* const, long unsigned int> > > >, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference, boost::convex_topology<2ul>::point_difference&> >::weight_type [2][2] {aka int [2][2]}’) to type ‘double (*)[2]’
 _difference_type delta = -linear_solver<Point::dimensions>::solve(dE_d_d, dE_d);
```

**EDIT**: Since this has become a different question, I started a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33905593/2725810).

Comment: No idea if this is the problem, but the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/kamada_kawai_spring_layout.html) states "The graph must be undirected and connected. " and yours is directed. You should probably add the tag [tag:boost-graph], it may help you get better answers.

Comment: @cv_and_he Thank you for the suggestion, but the error did not go away.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't read the error fully, it doesn't have an vertex_index_map. Is `setS` needed? changing it with `vecS` would probably solve the problem. If it's needed I'll need to check the algorithm to see.

Comment: My theory is that if you use `using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, undirectedS, State, CostType>;` it should work.

Comment: @cv_and_he Although I need `setS` (both for quickly accessing the bundled property and so that vertex descriptors should not get invalidated if a vertex is deleted), I tried vecS. Now the compiler complains: "error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::detail::graph::linear_solver " (with much more text following this)

Comment: Since using `setS` is required you'll need to create your own vertex_index_map, either internal or external. You can see an example using an external map [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8555715/2417774). Once you have that you'll need the following invocation: `kamada_kawai_spring_layout(
        g_, temp, get(edge_bundle, g_),
        square_topology<>(50.0), side_length(50.0), boost::layout_tolerance<CostType>(),
                                      CostType(1), 
                                      propmapIndex);`. No idea about your new error.

Comment: So, now I get that new error (please see the second update in the question).

Comment: @cv_and_he It looks like the problem is that CostType is `int` and not `double`...

Comment: Since this has become a different question, I started a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33905593/2725810